# How can i mount volume of glusterfs to /var/lib/docker in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker, glusterfs

I installed gluster-server and docker on ubuntu 14.04

```
# install Glusterfs
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties;
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:gluster/glusterfs-3.6;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install -y glusterfs-server;

gluster peer probe $NODE1_DNS;
gluster volume create file_store_docker replica 2 transport tcp $NODE1_DNS:/brickdocker $PUBLIC_DNS:/brickdocker force;
gluster volume start file_store_docker;
sudo mkdir /var/lib/docker;
mount -t glusterfs $PUBLIC_DNS:/file_store_docker /var/lib/docker;

# install Docker with AUFS
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get -y install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r);
sudo sh -c "wget -qO- https://get.docker.io/gpg | apt-key add -";
sudo sh -c "echo deb http://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main\ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list";
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get -y install lxc-docker;
```

When i run below line

```
sudo docker run -p 80:80 --name docker-wordpress-nginx -d eugeneware/docker-wordpress-nginx
```

And i got this message:

> Error response from daemon: error creating aufs mount to
>   /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/0b78a98c13f26eebcdef6517654ff80bdf6b35f433ac06be632aa55e8f3bb4a1-init:
>   file too large

Can you help me to understand this error? How do i mount volume of glusterfs to /var/lib/docker in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I got the answer for my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697861/how-can-i-mount-volume-of-glusterfs-to-var-lib-docker-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole lot of stuff in container file systems which gluster won't handle well.  e.g. think of the device files in `/dev`.  I'd also want to look closely at how gluster handles things like constant small appends to log files.

In any case there's little reason to share the containers themselves, when you can just fire up the appropriate containers on each host in the normal way to get that.  What you want to share is the volumes.  I suggest you use gluster only for that.  Keep in mind though that not everything volume mounted is appropriate for distributing like this.  e.g. if you have a container like logspout that talks to the docker socket on the host system.

Comment: Thanks your help, I think i maybe find other solution for that with ZFS not glusterfs. Let me try with that :)